# Handson table autocomplete strict mode with Thai language

Tags: jsp, handsontable

I have tried to use autocomplete strict mode after query data from the database. But some data are included Thai language, after I chose the data, which included Thai, the autocomplete cell will become red. However, it work fine with those data that included only English.
How can I solve this problem to make autocomplete strict mode work with Thai?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem now that I have to parse the text at the front (JSP) to UTF-8 before passing the text to the Servlet part.